# Parallel Operation Batching

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

Is there built-in support in the TPL (Task-Parallel-Library) for batching operations?

I was recently playing with a routine to carry out character replacement on a character array using a lookup table i.e. transliteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
{
    char replaceChar;

    if (lookup.TryGetValue(chars[i], out replaceChar))
    {
        chars[i] = replaceChar;
    }
}
```

I could see that this could be trivially parallelized, so jumped in with a first stab which I knew would perform worse as the tasks were too fine-grained:

```
Parallel.For(0, chars.Length, i =>
{
    char replaceChar;

    if (lookup.TryGetValue(chars[i], out replaceChar))
    {
        chars[i] = replaceChar;
    }
});
```

I then reworked the algorithm to use batching so that the work could be chunked onto different threads in less fine-grained batches. This made use of threads as expected and I got some near linear speed up.

I'm sure that there must be built-in support for batching in the TPL. What is the syntax, and how do I use it?

```
const int CharBatch = 100;
int charLen = chars.Length;

Parallel.For(0, ((charLen / CharBatch) + 1), i =>
{
    int batchUpper = ((i + 1) * CharBatch);

    for (int j = i * CharBatch; j < batchUpper && j < charLen; j++)
    {
        char replaceChar;

        if (lookup.TryGetValue(chars[j], out replaceChar))
        {
            chars[j] = replaceChar;
        }
    }
});
```

**Update**

After using @Oliver's answer and replacing `Parallel.For` with a [Parallel.ForEach and a Partitioner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991604.aspx) the code is as follows:

```
const int CharBatch = 100;

Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(0, chars.Length, CharBatch), range =>
{
    for (int i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++)
    {
        char replaceChar;

        if (lookup.TryGetValue(chars[i], out replaceChar))
        {
            chars[i] = replaceChar;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For better getting your head around you should get the [Patterns for Parallel Programming: Understanding and Applying Parallel Patterns with the .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=86b3d32b-ad26-4bb8-a3ae-c1637026c3ee&displaylang=en). It's a great source and explains the common ways on how to use the TPL.

Take a look at page 26 (Very small loop bodies). There you'll find this example:

```
Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(from, to), range =>
{
    for (int i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++)
    {
        // ... process i
    }
});
```

So the missing piece you're searching is the [`System.Concurrent.Collections.Partitioner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the link, but do you have a specific answer to my question?

Comment: That's brilliant thanks. Works perfectly and a very nice API too :) I have updated my question with an example based on your answer.