# How to break big foreach loop into batch and process it simultaneously?

Tags: c#, loops, c#-4.0, foreach, batch-processing

```
foreach (var deviceId in deviceList)
{
    // register device into IoT hub 
    Device device;
    RegistryManager registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString("connectionString");
    device = await registryManager.AddDeviceAsync(new Device(deviceId));

    // send message to iot hub
    DeviceClient deviceClient;
    await deviceClient.SendEventAsync("data");                       
}
```

if device are 10000 then how can i break it into multiple batch and process it?

I tried this code but its not promissing

```
public IEnumerable<user> GetBatch(int pageNumber)
{
    return users.Skip(pageNumber * 1000).Take(1000);
}
```

Comment: If you want to process "simultaneously" (in parallel), you could look at parellelizing the foreach. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564506/nesting-await-in-parallel-foreach for some approaches with `Async` and `Await`. If you want to chunk it into batches, `.Skip` and `.Take` are indeed the right way to do that.

Comment: Please, post working code. In this example `deviceClient == null`, so will be NRE.

Comment: `AddDeviceAsync` and `SendEventAsync` are CPU-bound or IO-bound operations? In the first case, it will be good to work in parallel, in the second case, need asynchronous code.

Comment: Is the `RegistryManager` thread safe? Can we add devices from different threads at the same time, or do we need lock?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a great case for a [Parallel.ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop) Loop, which will automatically distribute your loop processing across multiple threads.  Very easy to re-arrange your code into such a loop and utilize the built-in Parallel library to enable parallel processing.  This assumes of course that sequence doesn't really matter (and it doesn't seem to based on what little we can see).

**EDIT: 
If you do need specific batches of 100 or 200 as noted in your comment, you can use the [System.Collections.Concurrent.Partitioner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) class to break a parallel loop up as desired, [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613156/parallel-operation-batching) actually does a good job describing how to use it.**

```
Parallel.ForEach(devices, (device) =>
            {
                        // register device into IoT hub 
                        Device device;
            RegistryManager registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString("connectionString");
                        device = await registryManager.AddDeviceAsync(new Device(deviceId));


                        // send message to iot hub
                         DeviceClient deviceClient;
                        await deviceClient.SendEventAsync("data");                       

            });
```

Comment: but here we have not process it into batch . batch of 100 or 200. before Parallel.ForEach it will be great if we can batch it. can you help me? thanks

Comment: Correct, it's not broken into specific batches.  Can you share some more info in your post about the exact desired end result?  Is there a reason you want it into specific batches of 100 or 200?

Comment: i want to into batches because it is taking to much time to execute more no of device list. i do not want it into 100 or 200 any no is good for me.

Comment: In that case, the parallel loop as originally posted will do what you want.  It will use built-in .NET algorithms to break the processing up as efficiently as possible based on threads available on the current machine.

Comment: Neo, i believe you do not understand the concept of parallel.foreach. This is braking things up so it is handled in parallel and is then much faster. Yoy wanted it faster so i believe Steve helped you

Comment: I highly doubt this is effective code. Tasks will be spent most of the time in awaiting.

Comment: In addition, this code may be non-thread safe. Here we need clarification the author of the question.